# Header turns into fixed when user scrolls

Tags: css

In a web app, I have a header and want to make to keep showing it as the user scrolls, I used `position: fixed;` to achieve that but the body now starts from the top of the page as opposed to starting from underneath the header.

Originally:

[image]

Now:

[image]

What I want to do is give the header a fixed position when the user starts scrolling **or** give it a fixed position but keep that area under the header according to the height of the header (I can currently just add a div with fixed height in there but if the header changes that means i have to change that as well and it feels like a double up)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmp7fbrx/3/

Comment: Well how often do you plan on changing the height of the header?

Comment: @WilliamRobinson not that often but i don't want to leave surprises for the next developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a flex layout, then `.header` can be whatever height, and the rest of the page will automatically adapt.

Set `body` as the flex parent, and wrap `.body` and `.footer` in a new element and set that element to `flex-grow: 1` and `overflow: scroll` so that it will fill the rest of the window, and that element will scroll with overflow, and `.header` will stay put (mimicking `position: fixed`).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.body {
  min-height: 200vh; /* you can remove. just for demo purposes */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">My menu</div>
<main>
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</main>
```

Comment: That sounds awesome, but i tried to apply it to the current fiddle and it didn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/zmp7fbrx/5/

Comment: @NaguibIhab read the answer again. *"wrap .body and .footer in a new element and set that element to flex-grow: 1 and overflow: scroll"*

Answer (score 1):

You could just set `padding-top` of `body` to the header's height and add `top: 0` to header's css.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.header, .body, .footer {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.header {height: 50px;}
.body {text-align:center;}
.footer {}

.center-horiz{width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #666;  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="header">My menu</div>
<div class="body">some text2 
    <br>
    <div class="center-horiz">div centered horizontally</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">some text3</div>
```

Or you could give `.body` an `margin-top` of the header's height.

```css
.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.header, .body, .footer {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.header {height: 50px;}
.body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.body {text-align:center;}
.footer {}

.center-horiz{width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #666;  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="header">My menu</div>
<div class="body">some text2 
    <br>
    <div class="center-horiz">div centered horizontally</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">some text3</div>
```

Use JavaScript to get the header height on DOM loaded and set `margin-top` of the `.body` element. (this also works for dynamic height of the header)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var headerElement = document.querySelector('.header');
  var bodyElement = document.querySelector('.body');
  
  bodyElement.style.marginTop = headerElement.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
})
```

```css
.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.header, .body, .footer {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.header {height: 50px;}
.body {text-align:center;}
.footer {}

.center-horiz{width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #666;  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="header">My menu</div>
<div class="body">some text2 
    <br>
    <div class="center-horiz">div centered horizontally</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">some text3</div>
```

Note: If the header as and dynamic height which is changing on window resize, you have to add an `resize` listener which sets the margin on resize.

Comment: thank you for your answer cyrix. If the header's height gets adjusted that static height also needs to get adjusted. Can you think of a way in doing this without having the height in two places?

Comment: You could use something like `sass` and store the header height in a variable or use JavaScript to get the headers height and apply it to the body as padding or to .body as margin`, i'll add an example for the javascript part.

Comment: Please do, that sounds like the optimal solution :)

Comment: Added the javascript example and a note on dynamic header height.